# Group events by reasonable time periods

Tags: time, dashboard

I'm in the middle of creating some sort of dashboard that lists certain events grouped by the time frame they occured - something like this:

```
TODAY
   ....
YESTERDAY
   ...
MONDAY
   ...
LAST WEEK
   ...
```

The basic (incomplete) 'rules' are: There should be no empty groups (=headings), if 2 days only have 1 entry each they must be merged (e.g. "TWO DAYS AGO") and the precision reduces with the time passed since the event occured (MONDAY vs. LAST WEEK).

I know that the requirements are very unprecise - I was just wondering if there are any thoughts/concepts for this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, interface wise, I wouldn't go to so much trouble. I find it a bit frustrating to have designs that "change" significantly. So, personally, I'd want a grouping that is consistent, such that if, say, 15 events get added, it doesn't decide to re-organise on some arbitrary basis. So, my thoughts would be, think up a less complex scheme.

For us to help, I think you'll need to expand more on what you are doing.